# How do I figure the reason this fails? (crontab or path)

Tags: python, cron, digital-ocean

I'm using a Virtual Private Server for the time. I'm confused about why my script doesn't run via crontab, crontab -e :

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/python3.8 ~/root/bots/bot1.py 
* * * * * ( sleep 55 ; killall -g ~/bots/bot1.py )
```

yet in the terminal the following does work fine:

```
root@botnetwork:~/bots# python3 bot1.py
```

Am I mispecifying the path, I have tried a few different combinations and I'm not sure why its not working. (this is a Digi Ocean droplet).

Comment: root's home is in `/root`, not `~/root`

Comment: these variations also fail:
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 root/MyBots/Bot.py
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/MyBots/Bot.py
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 ~/MyBots/Bot.py
still stuck on this!!

Comment: Arkadiusz Drabczyk noticed something I didn't earlier, your paths are still incorrect.

You need a / before root, and you should use full paths not ~.

You also might be adding the crontab as a user without permission

Answer (score 1):

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/python3.8 /root/bots/bot1.py
```

Lib should be bin
Lib is where libraries are stored

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.8 /root/bots/bot1.py
```